# sapply in R - how to solve this without looping

Tags: r, lapply, sapply, mapply

How to use sapply? I have 400k records in my dataframe. Data needs to be populated to b$a1 without using for loop.

```
b <- a
b[1:100,]
for (i in 1:nrow(b)) {
    if (b`$`x[i] > mean(b`$`x) &
        b`$`y[i] > mean(b`$`y) &
        b`$`z[i] < mean(b`$`z))
    {
        b`$`a1[i] = '1'
    }
    else {
        b`$`a1[i] = '0'
    }
}
head(b)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can just use `ifelse()` here:

```
b$a1 <- ifelse(b$x > mean(b$x) & b$y > mean(b$y) & b$z > mean(b$z), 1, 0)
```

Akrun's update:

```
b$a1 <- as.integer(b$x > mean(b$x) & b$y > mean(b$y) & b$z > mean(b$z))
```

Comment: Code-golfing - `rowSums(b > t(colMeans(b)))==ncol(b)` or even `Reduce(\`&\`,Map(\`>\`,b,colMeans(b)))`

Comment: @thelatemail But wouldn't that assume that there are only three columns in `b`?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - true, but that can be adjusted easy enough - `Reduce(\`&\`,Map(\`>\`,b[vars], colMeans(b[vars])))` for the second one if `vars <- c("x","y","z")`

Answer (score 0):

the results are different from calculated values in Excel! i tried ifelse(), can u tell how can i use sapply here?